# To throw is human

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom, translation-check

So, if

> To err is human

translates to

> Errare humanum est

what would be a good translation for

> To throw (a stone or projectile) is human

I'm looking at *proicere humanum est* and *mittere humanum est*; *proicere* parallels with 'projectile', and *mittere* parallels with 'missile'.

In particular, the context of this is more in the

> drop a stone down a well to figure out how deep it goes

rather than

> throw a rock at a bird for hunting

Comment: I wonder if that "all ye who are without sin" thing could be adapted to fit this purpose.

Comment: @Nickimite I was going more for an exploration connotation instead of judgement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly both *mittere* and *projicere* are found in the Vulgate bible in the famous Joseph story where Joseph is thrown in a pit by his brethren ([Gen 37](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Gen%2037&version=KJV)). So on that authority alone I'd say both of your candidates would be sound choices.

However, it seems to me that [*demittere*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddemitto) may be also appropriate: *to send down; to drop; to let, sink, or bring down; to cause to hang or fall down; to lower, put down, let fall*

Depending on context, it may be interpreted as "lower" (e.g. *aliquem per funem in puteum demittere*) or as "drop" (*nummum in puteum demittere*).

Answer (score 1):

So, the way the construction works is a simple predicate nominative with *sum*, infinitives are considered neuter singular, ergo. Any word for throw you want will work with the same construction:

"X *est humanum*"

X being, *iacere, proicere, abicere, contorquere, torquere* etc.

Comment: Which verb do you find most suitable for the scenario in the question?

Comment: I still like both _mittere_ and _proicere_, but considering the audience for this, I think _proicere_ will be more obviously related to _projectile_ vs. the relation between _mittere_ and _missile_. So: _Proicere est humanum_